# Google script to copy specific cell values

Tags: spreadsheet

I need a little help with a google spreadsheet script. Currently I'm using a script to copy entire row if contition is met(checkbox TRUE/FALSE). If different condition is met(different checkbox), i need to copy that entire row to "Completed" AND the tricky part for me, I need to ONLY copy cells in A,B,P columns in that specific row to sheet "Flash" to position A,B,C.. Could someone help me? Thanks!

```
function onEdit(event) {

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var s = event.source.getActiveSheet();
  var r = event.source.getActiveRange();


  if(s.getName() == "Orders" && r.getColumn() == 9 && r.getValue() == true) {
    var row = r.getRow();
    var numColumns = s.getLastColumn();
    var targetSheet = ss.getSheetByName("Completed");
    var target = targetSheet.getRange(targetSheet.getLastRow() + 1, 1);
    s.getRange(row, 1, 1, numColumns).moveTo(target);
    s.deleteRow(row);
  } else if(s.getName() == "Orders" && r.getColumn() == 15 && r.getValue() == true) {

    var row = r.getRow();
    var numColumns = s.getLastColumn();


    var targetSheet = ss.getSheetByName("Completed");
    var target = targetSheet.getRange(targetSheet.getLastRow() + 1, 1);
    s.getRange(row, 1, 1, numColumns).copyTo(target);

    var targetSheet = ss.getSheetByName("Flash");
    var target = targetSheet.getRange(targetSheet.getLastRow() + 1, 1);
    s.getRange(row, 1, 1, numColumns).copyTo(target);

    s.deleteRow(row);
  }
}
```